Spring MVC application throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for DispatcherServlet in Apache Tomcat
I'm working on a Spring MVC project using Spring Tool Suite (STS) with Apache Tomcat. When I deploy the application, it fails to initialize the DispatcherServlet and throws a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.
Error Logs:
Here is the relevant part of the server logs:
Dec 22, 2024 8:56:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [myFrontController] in web application [/spring-hibernate-demo] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1120)
    ...


My project structure looks like this:
spring-hibernate-demo
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── com.example.controller
│   │   │   ├── com.example.entity
│   │   │   ├── com.example.service
│   │   │   └── com.example.config
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── WEB-INF
│   │       │   ├── templates (contains Thymeleaf templates)
│   │       │   ├── myFrontController-servlet.xml
│   │       │   └── web.xml
├── pom.xml


My web.xml configuration includes
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myFrontController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myFrontController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


My pom.xml includes Spring MVC dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.27</version>
</dependency>


What I Have Tried:
Verified that the spring-webmvc dependency is in the Maven pom.xml.
Checked the target folder, and the required Spring JARs (e.g., spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar) are not being included in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the deployed WAR file.
Ensured that Tomcat is configured properly with the correct deployment path.
Questions:
Why is the DispatcherServlet class not found in my application?
How can I ensure that the required Spring JARs are included in the deployment?

Could you see spring-webmvc-5.3.27.jar in target/WEB-INF/lib

yes , i see this
